# Grouping of objects ( permutations and combinations)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

number of ways of making groups of equal sizes from a bunch of 'p' identical type,'q' another type of identical objects and 'r' another type of identical objects. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIyZh.jpg)

Don't forget to look at the image( image is  just an example that is it tells about one of the case in my question)

Comment: your question is vague, and hard to follow.
Please correct, no. to number.
Will the group size always be 2?
Are we pulling from that alphabet every single time?  
In your picture isn't  ac duplicated?
What do the letters "tor" and "en" mean?

Comment: @nickalh thanks for suggesting, by the way it is just an example of my question and I didn't understand where I used 'tor' and 'en'. I didn't duplicate ac , here ac is used in two different grouping, my question is not to make different pairs , it's aim is to make groups and in that answer I have made 3 different sets of grouping.